# How to get the field values from vector layer in the list using gdal

Tags: python, gdal

I have a list with the field names and i am trying to get the field values using the code snippet:

```
from osgeo import osr,ogr, gdal
shp="filepath"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataSource = driver.Open(shp,0)
layer=dataSource.GetLayer()
list=['field1','field2','field3']
for i in layer:
    ValList = [i.GetField(j) for j in list]
```

i am getting the following error:

```
raise ValueError("Illegal field requested in GetField()")
ValueError: Illegal field requested in GetField()
```

So what i have to do if i want to get the values in the list?

Comment: Try printing out the field names using the code (last two lines) in this snippet: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-shapefile-fields-get-the-user-defined-fields. You might be asking for the wrong name.

Answer (score 3):

1. Try not using `list` a variable name as it is a reserved Python word.
2. Your code works fine for me, it looks like the error comes from your list of field.

This works fine for me:

```
from osgeo import ogr

shp= "your_shapefile_path"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

dataSource = driver.Open(shp, 0)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
list_field = ['existing_field']
for feature in layer:
    values_list = [feature.GetField(j) for j in list_field]
```

Comment: I had to add layer.ResetReading() to the end of your code block to get it to work properly (NOT indented as part of the for loop).  See the "Iterate over Features" section [here](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html)